# How to increase the size of labels of a legend for a raster and make them bold?

Tags: r, plot, raster

I want to plot a raster file.

```
library(colorRamps) 
library(raster) 

r <- raster(nrows=5, ncols=5, vals=1:25)
plot(r, col =  matlab.like(8))
```

This produces
[image]

As you can see, the legend has numbers from 5 to 25. These numbers are not so clear so I want to increase the size of them to be clear and make them bold. Thanks

Comment: Also you can check http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/guide_colourbar.html

Comment: many thanks. Is there a way to make them bold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass **axis.args** and **legend.args** as arguments to the legend only function call, as for image.plot in the fields package.

For example, to specify tick positions and labels, It will also accept arguments such as **legend.width** and **legend.shrink**.

```
plot(r, col=topo.colors(100), legend=TRUE, axes=TRUE)
r.range <- c(minValue(r), maxValue(r))
plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, col=topo.colors(100),
     legend.width=1, legend.shrink=0.75,
     axis.args=list(at=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], 25),
                    labels=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], 25), 
                    cex.axis=0.6),
     legend.args=list(text='Elevation (m)', side=4, font=2, line=2.5, cex=0.8))
```

Comment: @agstudy -- The examples section of `help(plot, package="raster")` is where I first found this. Otherwise -- though it's a little bit of work --  you can chase down the source code of the function that actually plots RasterLayer objects..

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks. I read the help but without a lot of success. I even go through the code of `getMethod(f='plot',signature=signature('Raster','ANY'))`(no need to download all the package).... I think I should get all the sources.

Comment: @agstudy -- With all the **raster** (and IIRC **sp**) plotting functions, you  have to get pretty quick at following a trail that often leads through several layers of wrapper functions. Here, you go from `getMethod("plot", c("Raster", "ANY"))` to `raster:::.plotraster` to `raster:::.imageplot` before you see `axis.args` and what is done with it. Takes a while to get used to, but on the other hand it's good to see how these functions actually work!